# run-as package unknown but it is shown on adb package list

Tags: android

android version: 5.0.1
using adb shell to connect to the device
and pm list package showing my package is com.example.jim.test10
By running run-as com.example.jim.test10
I get error: com.example.jim.test10 is unknown
In manifest of the app test10, debuggable is set to be true

Hope to see advice, thanks
Should there be any extra info needed, please tell me

Comment: What device model are you seeing this on?  This [old bug](https://code.google.com/p/android/issues/detail?id=58373) has been fixed  and released, but some people are reporting they still see it on Samsung devices.

Comment: Yes. That's a samsung device

Comment: I see the same problem on a Galaxy S4 running 5.0.1 but not on a Nexus tablet running 5.1.1.  Based on the AOSP issue I linked in my previous comment, I think this is a Samsung bug.

Comment: would consider that is a bug of Samsung device

Comment: I'm also seeing this on a Galaxy Tab a 7 runing 5.1.1